# Ember.Object JSON model data as Ember.computed.alias has no data properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm reworking an EAK app for Ember CLI, and have setup my old api-stub JSON test data to be served up by 'ember-cli-api-stub'. My Route model() function calls getJSON and passes the response data into "resolve(Ember.Object.create(data))". The corresponding Controller aliases this model data as a property with "RoomStay: Ember.computed.alias('RoomStays.RoomStay')". With CLI I get a warning "object proxying is deprecated, please use "model.RoomStay" instead.", so I prefix with 'model'. Now when I inspect the 'RoomStay' object in console pane from another Controller along the Route (console.log(this.controllerFor('avail'))), it doesn't have the data and child nodes which it should. It just has properties like '_dependentKeys', '_meta', 'altKey' and 'isDescriptor'. The aliases should just be pointers to the JSON data. Why are they something else now that I'm using CLI and not the old api-stub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias properties I described appear to be normal.

I was able to get to the data by changing "RoomStay: Ember.computed.alias('RoomStays.RoomStay')" to "RoomStay: Ember.computed.alias('model.RoomStays.RoomStay.firstObject')".